# Why does the whole box fill when I transform an object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, fill, distort

I'm an Illustrator rookie and having problems. Whenever I rotate or transform the object, the whole bounding box fills. See examples below. Rotating, perspective distort, etc all seem to have the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?!

Before transforming:
[image: Object before transforming]

After rotating (same problem with other transformations)
[image: Object after rotating - whole box is filled]

Comment: what kind of object is that? Have you checked other panels: layers, transparency, graphic styles... Would be helpful to have these open in the screenshots

Comment: Hi Bekahland, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your installed illustrator have graphic card problems! I recommend you change your preferences in edit menu and restart illustrator. It may be from system graphic card settings.

Answer (score 0):

It' can be a problem whit the software I'll think its good idea too reinstall again the illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding the object before transforming it. I've had illustrator bug out on me on me several times over simple things like not expanding or ungrouping objects.

Comment: And how can this be done? Can you add the commands or clicks one has to do? Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score -2):

Get rid of the bounding box and just use the vector image of the suitcase.

Comment: Well, and how can someone do that? Please explain it better and add an screenshot to visualize what you mean.  Usually an one-line-answer is not a valid answer ...  Welcome to GD.SE!